# chef bootstrap a node which is not connected to internet

Tags: chef-infra

How to chef bootstrap a vm which is not connected to internet. I know there is way to create bootstrap template and use the same during bootstrapping but any one tried this approach if yes can you please help me to bootstrap windows 2012 and redhat 7 vms.

Comment: bootstrap a node without connecting to the internet is something called an air-gapped environment. Please follow [link](https://docs.chef.io/install_chef_air_gap.html#create-a-bootstrap-template) to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

The workstation that executes `knife bootstrap` needs SSH connectivity within the vm to bootstrap and then this latter needs connectivity with the Chef Server that contains cookbooks to use on bootstrap's run list.

Take a look at the following video that shows in quick how the bootstrap work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=7szFHZRVNCU